# Как сделать прокрутку фона медленней чем прокрутку контента

Tags: javascript, html, css

Мне нужно, чтобы фон для блока с классом `bg1` покручивался медленней чем контент в этом блоке. Можете подсказать как это сделать. Видел такие эффекты на других сайтах получается очень красиво, решил сам попробовать, так сделать, но не пойму, как это реализовать.

```css
.Skills
 &-uppertext
  margin-top: 100px
  margin-bottom: 100px
  text-align: center
  span:first-child
   font-family: "CircleRegular"
   font-size: 45px
   color: #272727
   margin-right: 5px
  span:last-child
   font-family: "CircleBold"
   font-size: 45px
   color: #272727
.Items
 display: flex
 flex-direction: column
 margin: 10px
.Items-main
 background-color: #fff
 border-radius: 10px
 box-shadow: 0px 15px 20.8px 0.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08)
.Items-header
 font-family: "CircleBold"
 font-size: 18px
 color: #272727
 text-align: center
.Items-text
 font-family: "CircleRegular"
 font-size: 16px
 color: #272727
 text-align: center
 margin-bottom: 90px
.Items-img-span
 text-align: center
 padding-bottom: 40px
 margin-top: 40px
.Items-main-bgc
 background-image: linear-gradient(266deg, #00b1e7, #00e3ac)
 border-radius: 10px
 box-shadow: 0px 15px 20.8px 0.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08)
.SecondSkills
 margin-bottom: 120px
 .bg1
 background-image: url(../img/bg1.png)
 background-size: cover
 background-repeat: no-repeat
 margin-bottom: 90px
```

```html
<div class="row bg1 justify-content-center">
   <div class="col-12">
    <p class="Skills-uppertext">
     <span>WHY</span>
     <span>WE</span>
    </p>


   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-7 col-sm-9 col-10">
    <div class="Items-main">
     <div class="Items">
      <span class="Items-img-span">
       <img class="Items-img" src="./img/-----28.png" alt="">
      </span>
      <p class="Items-header">Just BTC and PayPal</p>
      <p class="Items-text">We are providing safe and secure online BTC converter to most popular direction - PayPal </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-7 col-sm-9 col-10">
    <div class="Items-main-bgc">
     <div class="Items">
      <span class="Items-img-span">
       <img class="Items-img" src="./img/-----29.png" alt="">
      </span>
      <p class="Items-header">Safe & Secure & Trusted
      </p>
      <p class="Items-text">Anybody can be sure that they have place where they can exchange BTC to PyaPal absolutely riskfree.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-7 col-sm-9 col-10">
    <div class="Items-main">
     <div class="Items">
      <span class="Items-img-span">
       <img class="Items-img" src="./img/-----30.png" alt="">
      </span>
      <p class="Items-header">Feel it like in 5 star hotel
      </p>
      <p class="Items-text">Feel it like in president apartments. It's comfortable to use our service, we have fast support and everything is smooth.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="w-100"></div>

  
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-7 col-sm-9 col-10">
    <div class="Items-main">
     <div class="Items">
      <span class="Items-img-span">
       <img class="Items-img" src="./img/-----28.png" alt="">
      </span>
      <p class="Items-header">Just BTC and PayPal</p>
      <p class="Items-text">We are providing safe and secure online BTC converter to most popular direction - PayPal </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-7 col-sm-9 col-10">
    <div class="Items-main">
     <div class="Items">
      <span class="Items-img-span">
       <img class="Items-img" src="./img/-----28.png" alt="">
      </span>
      <p class="Items-header">Just BTC and PayPal</p>
      <p class="Items-text">We are providing safe and secure online BTC converter to most popular direction - PayPal </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-7 col-sm-9 col-10">
    <div class="Items-main">
     <div class="Items">
      <span class="Items-img-span">
       <img class="Items-img" src="./img/-----28.png" alt="">
      </span>
      <p class="Items-header">Just BTC and PayPal</p>
      <p class="Items-text">We are providing safe and secure online BTC converter to most popular direction - PayPal </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/235531/

Comment: Есть готовые плагины для этого, [к примеру вот этот.](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/ru/) Вы такое ищите?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $(".bg").css("background-position","0% " + ($(this).scrollTop() / 30 - 10 ) + "px");
});
```

```css
*{
margin:0;
}

.bg{ 
background:url(https://poster.nicefon.ru/2016_06/13/800x450/35031def0e88da898e5e5.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-y;
background-position: 50% 0;    
transition: 0s linear;
transition-property: background-position;
 background-attachment:fixed;
}
p{
font-size:2em;
width:80%;
margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="bg">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium veniam beatae voluptas, quis aliquid aut nam nulla voluptatum, harum sunt asperiores fuga aliquam ducimus porro dolore fugiat nihil, perspiciatis, ab sequi! Reprehenderit modi hic
    cum ullam blanditiis totam quaerat tempore, veniam veritatis illum. Sequi culpa aliquam eos reprehenderit! Voluptas, accusamus, provident! Incidunt aliquam, aspernatur quidem facilis! Unde in ipsa quis harum! Reprehenderit, quas eius obcaecati. Quae
    distinctio pariatur nostrum dolor sed, magni. Ex possimus itaque adipisci non, id impedit illum nulla repudiandae nesciunt quo quaerat, tempora omnis beatae doloribus eveniet error quasi, in tempore placeat consequuntur dignissimos inventore facilis
    sed quis. Veritatis rem consectetur dolores enim, qui maxime ex. Assumenda, amet nemo ex cumque accusamus obcaecati excepturi deserunt consequuntur deleniti perspiciatis odio possimus voluptas, inventore provident velit distinctio quos. Odit distinctio,
    dolores fugit nulla repudiandae et sapiente architecto. Ea eveniet animi nemo, iusto magnam minima ipsum commodi! Magnam quibusdam possimus, sint consequatur beatae quae quaerat quia praesentium voluptatibus sit. Consectetur non iure architecto sit
    in vero nobis vel eum sequi quia dolorum cumque nemo eligendi at voluptatibus earum quos commodi perferendis laboriosam aliquid aperiam tempora ut, quidem nulla? Ut doloremque eum, dicta quia debitis labore pariatur asperiores numquam incidunt id
    neque, ea dolorum dolores placeat sequi obcaecati ad voluptatibus porro aut impedit vitae optio nihil harum? Natus aspernatur debitis recusandae blanditiis assumenda quia saepe, laborum quaerat facere iste, est ut voluptas rerum temporibus aliquam
    velit doloremque excepturi at pariatur nostrum doloribus illum cupiditate nemo voluptatum beatae. Cupiditate, voluptas. Quasi accusantium expedita omnis quae ratione saepe provident tenetur eligendi! Odio, atque, ab. Deserunt quo laborum cum nostrum,
    deleniti praesentium quibusdam ea ex autem molestiae laboriosam similique animi corporis debitis magni pariatur dicta officiis odit voluptate ipsum! Ullam iusto perferendis optio asperiores distinctio quos unde ex officiis culpa. Ipsa quo exercitationem,
    nihil! </p>
</div>
```